# While downloading files using firebase storage -The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using `NotificationCompat.Builder` while uploading/downloading files in Firebase. While uploading it is normal. However, when downloading the system lags until download is completed and log cat shows

> The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

This is code of `addOnprogresslistner()`

```
public void onProgress(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
    double fprogress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
    String progress = String.format("%.2f", fprogress);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = 
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download)
        .setContentTitle("Downloading " + model.getName())
        .setContentText(" " + progress + "% completed" );

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = 
       (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
}
```

If I remove the `NotificationCompat.Builder`, it works just fine.

Any workaround?

Comment: How often is `onProgress()` called?

Comment: Side note, don't forget you could show a progress bar too https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setProgress(int,%20int,%20boolean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `onPregress` method is getting called very often as uploading and downloading progress.

you just have to add a condition, check following code:

```
public void onProgress(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
double fprogress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
int bytes = taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred();

String progress = String.format("%.2f", fprogress);
int constant = 1000;
if(bytes%constant == 0)
{
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = 
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download)
    .setContentTitle("Downloading " + model.getName())
    .setContentText(" " + progress + "% completed" );

NotificationManager mNotificationManager = 
   (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
}

}
```

I hope it would help.

Comment: This will only update progress when it is at 0 or 100%, you might want to try fprogress%10 == 0 or something?

Comment: @zgc7009 yes its just a demo, just change 100 to any other constant. I have edited answer.

Comment: @zgc7009 he is working with bytes not percent here, so may be he needs to make 100 to 1000 or more.

Comment: It may be better to save and compare with the last progress in case `fprogress` isn't changing between calls. That way it is guaranteed to create the notification no more than 100 times per task.

Comment: `(100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();` is just a percentage. You might want to save fprogress like @Jonathan727 suggested and then do something like `if((100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount()) - fprogress < 10) return;`. That way it can get updated if the percentage change is greater than or equal to 10% more than the last time you updated. That will give you a max of 10 updates

Comment: @Jonathan727 but it is not about calls only, how many times onProgress is getting called is the problem here. So as less often calls as better will be and off course shouldn't be less than 2 calls(in case of very small file).

Comment: onProgress was the problem and this seems to solve it. Thanks guys.